# Yii gridview ajax custom button before send updating the cell value

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii

Am facing the problem of showing the loader.gif beforesend function via ajax in the yii gridview in a particular related cell value. here is my gridview.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'deals-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->mersearch(),

'columns'=>array(
    'title',
    'description',
    array('header'=>'Valid Till','name'=>'valid','value'=>$data->valid),
    array('name' => 'status',
                'value'=>array($this,'getStatus'),
                'filter' => $active,'sortable'=>TRUE,
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'status'),
                ),
    array
            (   
            'name'=>'image',
                 'type'=>'image',
                            'value'=>array($this,'imagePath'),
                            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'thumb','rel'=>'gallery'),
            ),
 array(
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
'buttons'=>array
(

  'mail' => array
    (   
  'label'=>'mail',
  'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/mail.png',
  'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("deals/sendmail", array("id"=>$data->id))',
  'options' => array( 'ajax' => array('url'=>'js:$(this).attr("href")',
'beforeSend'=>'function(){
 var obj= $(".mail");
  obj.parent().parent().find(".status").replaceWith("<td class=\"status\"><img src=\"/images/loading.gif\"></td>");}',
                                                                'success'=>'function(data){$(".status").html("Mail Sent Successfully.")
                                                                    }',
                                    ),
                                                     'class'=>'mail',
                                    )),                                 

        ),
         'template'=>'{update}{delete}{mail}',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

The main problem is that When i click on sendmail button it replace all the parent status class cell with loading.gif but i just want to replace only that row status cell replaced but not all.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

`var obj= $(".mail");`

you get all cells, because each one of them have the class "mail".

You should get only the one clicked. Try

`var obj= $(this);`

I didn't tested, it's an idea.